# Mathematical equations with jQuery UI Slider

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

I have multiple sliders and it updates the total slider accordingly per each slider. When I go to slide another slider it subtracts it again from the original total value and not the updated value that was from subtracting the previous slider amount.

```
      // Photographer Slider
      $('#TablePhotographer').toggle(this.checked);
        $(function() {
          $( "#photo-range-min" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: photo,
            min: 1,
            max: photo,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#photo_amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
              $( "#total_amount").val("$" + (Number(ui.value) + Number(CityValue - photo)));
            }
          });

          $( "#photo_amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#photo-range-min" ).slider( "value" ).toFixed(2) );
        });

    // Ceremony Slider
      $('#TableCeremony').toggle(this.checked);
        $(function() {
          $( "#ceremony-range-min" ).slider({
            range: "min",
            value: ceremony,
            min: 1,
            max: ceremony,
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
              $( "#ceremony_amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value );
              $( "#total_amount").val("$" + (Number(ui.value) + Number(CityValue - ceremony)));
            }
          });
        //total slider
        $('.BudgetTable').fadeIn(500);
        $( "#total-range-min" ).slider({
          range: "min",
          value: CityValue,
          min: 1,
          max: CityValue,
          slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#total_amount" ).val( "$" + ui.value);
          }
        });
        $('#state_cost').text("Based on your selecttion, the average wedding cost in this state is $" + CityValue);
        $( "#total_amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#total-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) );
```

As you can see, 2 sliders subtract from the same value, but I need to store the changed value per slider and show them in the total slider. I want to be able to be able to update the value according to each slider.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: I tried setting it up but it was having some issues reading the url for the jQuery UI scripts. I will continue to try.